# Very basic alarm clock does not open webbrowser

Tags: python, if-statement, alarm, python-webbrowser

I'm totally new to programming. Wanted to write this basic alarm clock with Python but the webbrowser just doesn't open. I think it is probably my if statement that doesn't work. Is that correct?

```
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser

name = raw_input("What's your name?")
print ("Hello %s! Let me set an alarm for you. Please answer the following questions about when you want to wake up.")%(name)
alarm_h = raw_input("--> Please enter the hour when I should wake you up:")
alarm_m = raw_input("--> Please enter the exact minute of the hour:")
alarm_sound = raw_input("--> Please enter the Youtube-URL of your favorite song:")

now = datetime.today()

print ("It's now %s h : %s m. We'll wake you up at %s h : %s m." %(now.hour,   now.minute, alarm_h, alarm_m))

if now.hour == alarm_h and now.minute == alarm_m:
    webbrowser.open(alarm_sound, new=2)
```

Comment: You need to loop for tests, i propose to you to use `threads`.

Comment: You should think about the different datatypes of `now` which of type `datetime.datetime`, `now.hour` which is `int` and the `alarm_x` inputs since those are strings. I assume that because of the different datatypes your if statement would not become true since `now.hour == '14'` returns `False` (local time is 14:04 in Berlin currently).

Comment: Besides this, you should use `.format()` to concat a string with your variables and you need to implement something like an background process to check the time in order to raise the alarm. As @zetysz mentioned, `threads` would be suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code looks like it is checking the current time against the set alarm time. However, you currently have just one check, but you need to either loop and continuously compare the current time with the set alarm time or use another method of continuously checking.

The webbrowser line does work. Its not executing because the current time never reaches the alarm time (since you are not continuously comparing the current time with the set alarm time).

Try:

```
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser

name = raw_input("What's your name?")
print ("Hello %s! Let me set an alarm for you. Please answer the following questions about when you want to wake up.")%(name)
alarm_h = raw_input("--> Please enter the hour when I should wake you up:")
alarm_m = raw_input("--> Please enter the exact minute of the hour:")
alarm_sound = raw_input("--> Please enter the Youtube-URL of your favorite song:")

now = datetime.today()

print ("It's now %s h : %s m. We'll wake you up at %s h : %s m." %(now.hour, now.minute, alarm_h, alarm_m))

webbrowser.open(alarm_sound, new=2) #Added temporarily to test webbrowser functionality

if str(now.hour) == alarm_h and str(now.minute) == alarm_m: #Converted integer type to string type to match datatype of alarm_h and alarm_m
    webbrowser.open(alarm_sound, new=2)
```

This should open the webbrowser so you can test its functionality.

I also converted **now.hour** and **now.minute** to type string to match the datatypes of **alarm_h** and **alarm_m**. They were both integers and which can't be directly compared to a string datatype.

Definitely look into looping or threads for continuously updating the current time and checking if it equals the current thread.

Comment: Besides the threading thing, as I mentioned above, there could be some datatype incompatibilities preventing the if statement to become true.

Comment: Thanks for the input, helped me out a lot!
In the end, I used a while loop with a break at the end:
    while True:
        if str(now.hour) == alarm_h and str(now.minute) == alarm_m: 
            print ("Here goes you favorite song. Happy waking up!")
            webbrowser.open(alarm_sound, new=2)
            break

Comment: Glad I could help. Thats definitely option - you also might want to run that loop using a thread so that you don't lock your script to only that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple example.

```
from datetime import datetime
import webbrowser
import threading


name = raw_input("What's your name?")
print ("Hello %s! Let me set an alarm for you. Please answer the following questions about when you want to wake up.")%(name)
alarm_h = raw_input("--> Please enter the hour when I should wake you up:")
alarm_m = raw_input("--> Please enter the exact minute of the hour:")
alarm_sound = raw_input("--> Please enter the Youtube-URL of your favorite song:")
print alarm_sound
now = datetime.today()

def test():
    webbrowser.open(alarm_sound)

s1 = '%s:%s'
FMT = '%H:%M'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s1% (alarm_h, alarm_m), FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1%(now.hour, now.minute), FMT)

l = str(tdelta).split(':')
ecar = int(l[0]) * 3600 + int(l[1]) * 60 + int(l[2])
print ecar

threading.Timer(ecar, test).start()
```

We use `threading` to open a `webbrowser` after `n seconds`. in you example you ask user for hour and minute, in this way we calculate diffrence between two times using just `hours and minutes`.

If you need more explanation just comment.